# Нужна помощь с добавлением orders в profile page

Tags: python, django

Перед мной стоит задача на страницу профиля добавить историю заказов конкретного пользователя. Пытался через ForeignKey обратиться к OrderItem в модели Profile, не работает. по данному вопросу инфы гугл не дал. Подскажите к какому разделу документации мне обратиться.

orders app:

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import OrderItem
from .forms import OrderCreateForm
from cart.cart import Cart
from shop.models import Category
from .tasks import order_created


def order_create(request):
    cart = Cart(request)
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = OrderCreateForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            order = form.save(commit=False)
            if cart.coupon:
                order.coupon = cart.coupon
                order.discount = cart.coupon.discount
            order.save()
            for item in cart:
                OrderItem.objects.create(order=order,
                                         product=item['product'],
                                         price=item['price'],
                                         quantity=item['quantity'])
        cart.clear()
        order_created.delay(order.id)
        return render(request, 'orders/order_created.html',
                      {'order': order,
                       'categories': categories})
    else:
        form = OrderCreateForm
    return render(request, 'orders/order_create.html',
                  {'cart': cart,
                   'form': form,
                   'categories': categories})
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from shop.models import Product
from decimal import Decimal
from django.core.validators import MinValueValidator, MaxValueValidator
from coupons.models import Coupon


class Order(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField()
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    paid = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    coupon = models.ForeignKey(Coupon,
                               on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                               related_name='orders',
                               null=True,
                               blank=True)
    discount = models.IntegerField(default=0,
                                   validators=[MinValueValidator(0),
                                               MaxValueValidator(100)])

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-created',)
        verbose_name = 'Заказ'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Заказы'

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Order {}'.format(self.id)

    def get_total_cost(self):
        total_cost = sum(item.get_cost() for item in self.items.all())
        return total_cost - total_cost * (self.discount / Decimal('100'))


class OrderItem(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                              related_name='items')
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                related_name='order_items')
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.id)

    def get_cost(self):
        return self.price * self.quantity
```

users app:

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField('Фото', default='default.jpg',
                              upload_to='profile_pics')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'
```

views.py

```
@login_required  # makes imposible to go to the profile page when not authenticated
def profile(request):
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        u_form = UserUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(request.POST,
                                   request.FILES,
                                   instance=request.user.profile)
        if u_form.is_valid() and p_form.is_valid():
            u_form.save()
            p_form.save()
            messages.success(request, f'Аккаунт был успешно изменен.')
            return redirect('profile')

    else:
        u_form = UserUpdateForm(instance=request.user)
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(instance=request.user.profile)
    context = {
        'u_form': u_form,
        'p_form': p_form,
        'categories': categories,
    }
    return render(request, 'users/profile.html', context)
```

Comment: А как можно вывести заказы юзера, если с ним не связаны они?

Comment: натолкнул на мысль о чем читать. спасибо)